# Why can't I import a module?

Tags: python, module

I would like to be able to use the `iter_errors` function from the module [jsonschema](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validate.html#jsonschema.IValidator.iter_errors). I've imported the module, jsonschema, but cannot access iter_errors.

I suspect this might be because the module needs to be updated, and if this is the case, how do I do this?

I tried reinstalling it, and python prompted me to use the command 'upgrade', which I'm unsure how to use.

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jsonschema in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Cl
```

Thanks!

---

RE COMMENT:

I'm following the code usage [here](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validate.html#jsonschema.IValidator.iter_errors), which calls the function from the validator class:

EX CODE:

```
>>> schema = {
...     "type" : "array",
...     "items" : {"enum" : [1, 2, 3]},
...     "maxItems" : 2,
... }
>>> v = Draft3Validator(schema)
>>> for error in sorted(v.iter_errors([2, 3, 4]), key=str):
...     print(error.message)
4 is not one of [1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4] is too long
```

MY CODE:
where x is sample JSON

```
with open('gc_schema_test.json', 'r') as handle:
     schema = json.load(handle)

v = Draft3Validator(schema)
for error in sorted(v.iter_errors(x), key=str):
    print(error.message)
```

Comment: What's the actual code you're trying to use to access `iter_errors`? `import` just imports the module name into your namespace; you'll need `jsonschema.iter_errors` most likely.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can update a module with pip as it says there by passing `--upgrade` (or `-U`).

```
pip install -U jsonschema
```

The latest release as of today is 2.0.0.

(`iter_errors` has been around for quite a while though).

Once you have a recent version, make sure that like the example shows you make a * validator * instance to call it on. It's a method of validators, not a function.

So if you do

```
from jsonschema import Draft3Validator
```

your example should produce what you want.